# Importar CSV e converter data no formato dd/mm/yyyy para yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: sql, python, sql-server

Sou totalmente iniciante em programação, tanto em Python quanto Sql e por isso tenho algumas dúvidas que podem parecer básicas.
Recebo um arquivo .CSV que vem muitas informações não compatíveis com o Sql então sempre tenho que mudar manualmente e fazer o import  usando o seguinte comando:

```
BULK INSERT clientes
FROM 'C:\import\clientes.csv'
WITH
(
FIRSTROW = 2,
FIELDTERMINATOR = ';',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
ERRORFILE = 'C:\import\clientesErro.csv',
TABLOCK
)
```

(esse exemplo peguei da internet mas é o que eu uso) acontece que, tenho umas colunas com formato de data e gostaria de converter as datas que vem em dd/mm/aaa para aaa-mm-dd.
Também precisaria converter números onde são separadas as casa decimais com "," exemplo:1001,10 para 1001.10 mas creio que resolvendo o problema das datas consigo resolver esse também.

Comment: A afirmação "*gostaria de converter as datas que vem em dd/mm/aaaa para aaaa-mm-dd que é o padrão aceito pelo sql como formato de data*" não é correta.  O SQL Server aceita vários formatos de entrada e armazena internamente as datas em formato totalmente diferente, que inclusive varia com o tipo de dados utilizado (date, datetime, datetime2 etc). // Para fornecer a data no formato dd/mm/aaaa, uma forma é convert(date, coluna_entrada, 103).

Comment: Olá, removi a parte "que é o padrão aceito pelo sql como formato de data" da minha pergunta, acho que ficou melhor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui resolver desta forma:

(neste ponto estou considerando que já tenha conseguido fazer a conexão com seu banco de dados).

Importe esses caras:

```
import os
#esse __init__é o arquivo onde salvei as conexões com o banco de dados
from __init__ import mycursor, connection
# csv é o modulo que é usado para ler o arquivo csv
import csv
# modulo datetime é usado para tratar strings como formato de data
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta, datetime
```

apos a importar usei esse comando:
Observação: esse comando não é obrigatório, apenas usei ele pois meu código precisava ler varias vezes o mesmo arquivo, então melhor salvar em uma variável.

```
caminho_arquivo = './arquivos/seu_arquivo.txt'
```

agora vamos ler o arquivo: Atenção para o encoding eu usei latin-1 pois meu arquivo estava salvo neste padrão, pode ser que o seu esteja em outro encoding e isso poderá gerar erros nos acentos e 'ç'.

```
def ler_e_inserir_arquivo():
    with open(caminho_arquivo, newline='', encoding="latin-1") as arquivo:
        conteudo = csv.reader(arquivo, delimiter=';')
        for coluna in conteudo:
            query_com_insert = (
                "INSERT INTO nome_tabela(cd_cred,operacao,sigla_assessoria,data_atual)" "VALUES (%(cd_cred)s, %(operacao)s,%(sigla_assessoria)s,%(data_atual)s) "
            )
            tratamento_dos_dados = {
                'cd_cred': coluna[0],
                'operacao': coluna[1],
                'sigla_assessoria': coluna[2],
                'data_atual': datetime.strptime(coluna[3], "%d/%m/%Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
            }
            mycursor.execute(query_com_insert, tratamento_dos_dados)
            connection.commit()
```

Vamos agora por partes:

Neste ponto estou informando ande quero inserir os dados (query igual do sql)

```
INSERT INTO nome_tabela(cd_cred,operacao,sigla_assessoria,data_atual)
```

já nesto ponto estou passando onde estão os valores, observe que existe um %(nome)s. Dentro desses parentes está o nome do campo que defini no dicionario de dados.

```
"VALUES (%(cd_cred)s, %(operacao)s,%(sigla_assessoria)s,%(data_atual)s)
```

o "tratamento_dos_dados" é o meu dicionário nele eu atribuo uma chave e depois o seu valor:

quando a query buscar no dicionario a palavra 'cd_cred' vou passar a informação que está na coluna[0] do meu arquivo (lembrando que em python as listas começam em 0).

Agora vem aparte que todos buscavam, como transformar a data:

```
'data_atual': datetime.strptime(coluna[3], "%d/%m/%Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

usei o modulo datetime e "disse" para o payton que aquela string que estava na coluna[3] deveria ser tratado como formate de data dd/mm/aaaa (20/12/2017 por exemplo) e logo na sequencia uso o .strftime estou pedindo para o python converter a minha data para o padrão aaa-mm-dd (2017-12-20 por exemplo).

Depois disso passo para o cursor que foi definido no arquivo **init** executar os comandos:

```
        mycursor.execute(query_com_insert, tratamento_dos_dados)
        connection.commit()
```

pronto. Agora é só colocar no final do seu arquivo já fora do laço de repetição o comando:

ler_e_inserir_arquivo()

Assim você está 'chamando' a função que foi definida nos passos anteriores. Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

É importante você ter familiaridade com [expressões regulares](http://turing.com.br/material/regex/python_re.html):

```
import re
```

A sentença abaixo muda o formato de datas:

```
re.sub('(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})', r"\3-\2-\1", '19/05/2017')
```

Resultado:

```
>>> re.sub('(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})', r"\3-\2-\1", '19/05/2017')
'2017-05-19'
```

Para o caso de valores financeiros, seria algo assim:

```
re.sub('(\d+),(\d{2})', r"\1.\2", '1001,10')
```

Resultado:

```
>>> re.sub('(\d+),(\d{2})', r"\1.\2", '1001,10')
'1001.10'
```

Comment: Olá Cigano, muito obrigado pelo comentário.
Essa solução seria aplicada no Python certo? No caso eu precisaria criar algo no Python para editar o .csv e inserir essas linhas que você sugeriu?
Estava pensando em algo via sql e/ou futuramente migrar a edição para o Python

Comment: Sim, é para o Python. Você precisa criar um script `.py` e executá-lo passando o nome do arquivo SQL como parâmetro. Observe que, para o `re.sub`, o terceiro parâmetro deve ser substituído pelo conteúdo do seu arquivo.